# Django ID based dynamic URL with base64

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a django application that takes an ID based dynamic URL, but rather than having the URL be straight up the ID, as it is right now:

> url(r'^history/(?P< id>[0-9]+)/$', views.history)

I would like the URL to be the base64 encoded version of the object's ID, and i couldn't find a lot about encoding Django URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like to have base64 encoded ids, pretty bad choice for URL string as it has signs that aren't URL friendly

You should extend your object with extra field that contains for instance random generated slug or UUID and have it as parameter in URL instead of id

then you would query in your view by that field

Comment: i was planning on using UUID's in the first place, but the strings generated by UUID are way too long to fit in a URL, and i don't want the URL's to look like mysite.com/1 , mysite,com/2 etc

Comment: Then generate your own random sequence, base64 is not suitable as it has signs like = which should be parsed to be used in url. Also note out that more chars you have bigger the number of unique ones you can represent.

Comment: In what way are UUIDs too long for a URL? A UUID is only 36 characters long.